# Where can end-of-day data be downloaded for corporate bonds?

Tags: bonds, historical-data, market-data, fixed-income

I would like to download historical end-of-day prices for corporate bonds. What are some websites for doing so? I do not mind paying for the data but Bloomberg is too expensive, even though it is very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one from a Bloomberg partnership, it is [free](http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Results.jsp). To get the end of day prices, you may need some programming done. PM me if you need help with that.

Getting bond quotes and general information about a bond issue is considerably more difficult than researching a stock or a mutual fund. A major reason for this is that there is not a lot of individual investor demand for the information; therefore, most bond information is available only through higher level tools that are not accessible to the average investor.

Read more: Where can I get bond market quotes? | Investopedia http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/bondquote.asp#ixzz3wXVwv3s5